# Swift PaperOnboarding Module Import Error

Tags: swift, xcode, import

I am sorry for such simple question, but I've searched everywhere and read through the paper-onboarding documentation but still can't find a solution to this problem.

I am building a simple iOS app project using the [paper-onboarding library](https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding), by following this [YT tutorial](https://youtu.be/G5UkS4Mrepo?t=5m57s). I keep receiving the error: `No such module 'PaperOnboarding'`

```
import UIKit
import PaperOnboarding // <<<ERROR HERE>>>
class OnboardingView: PaperOnboarding {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

I'm not sure how to solve this, could someone shed some light on this?
Xcode: Version 9.3
Cocoapod: Version 1.4.0
Paper-onboarding: Version 4.0.2

Comment: Did you click on the white <project>.podspec file to open Xcode?(You should not open the .xcodeproj file if you're using Pods.)

Comment: Yeah, I use the `.xcworkspace` to open instead of the regular `.xcodeproject`

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with the library. It's definitely an error on your part or on the configuration of your project.

How are you adding the library to your project?

If you're adding using CocaPods:

`Make sure you do pod install or pod update
After that always open the .xcworkspace file in your project and not the .xcodeproj`

If you are opening the correct file:

`Check the POD project and the target for the pod you added and in the build settings, make sure Swift Version matches your project version.`

`Clean your project and run`

`Close and re-open XCode`

but it could be several other things. But make sure all the configuration is correct.
Some Pods require you to use the `use frameworks!` statement in the Podfile.